# How to restore backup.bz2 file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm new in postgresql ,have backup file : backup_03_17.backup.brz2

I know i can restore .backup file with pg_restore but how restore .backup.bz2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bzip2 -d can unzip .bz2 files. So unzip your backup file and send it to pg_restore.

Comment: you mean `bzip2 -d backup_03_17.backup.brz2` ?

Comment: If you're on Windows, just download  7zip, extract and try again.

Comment: bzcat  backup_03_17.backup.brz2 | pg_restore -d db_name

Comment: On Ubuntu I use `bunzip2 backup_03_17.dump.bz2;` `pg_restore -d <DB_NAME> -e backup_03_17.dump`.